# Mogrify / ImageMagick change jpeg background from grey to white

Tags: image, imagemagick, mogrify

we run a mogrify batch job like `mogrify -path "WEBREADY\DONE" -layers merge -trim +repage -resize "1200x1200>" -define jpeg:extent=500kb -format jpg *.*`

This works fine for images with a white background. But recently we saw a 2% error rate and discovered the error. Mogrify trims as expected only on the web the images is surrounded by white so this looks quite silly with grey-ish in corners.

THe solution would be to either

- Detect the non-white background. And in that case -only- do not trim
- Or to detect the background color (it is JPG) in top left corner and forst set this to an all white background.

Can this be done in my 1 command above for the commandline? (so find the grey background first and change it to white)

[image: example - original images is very highres]

Comment: Please show a silly image with greyish corners, so we can see what you mean. I suspect the answer is to add `-fuzz 35%` or similar near the start of your command, but let's see one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the colour of the top-left pixel like this:

```
convert shirt.jpg -crop 1x1+0+0 txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,srgb
0,0: (57311,57311,57311)  #DFDFDF  srgb(223,223,223)
```

So, it is #DFDFDF.

If you now try and replace that shade with yellow (I know you want white but you can't see that on here):

```
convert shirt.jpg -fill yellow -opaque "#DFDFDF" result.png
```

[image]

and you can now see the problem. The background is not uniform and its colour also appears in your shirt. If you add some `fuzz`, it makes it more pronounced:

```
convert shirt.jpg -fill yellow -fuzz 10% -opaque "#DFDFDF" result.png
```

[image]

Even if you try flood filling from the top-left, you still have to hope that there are no pixels in the edges of your shirt that are similar to that corner:

```
convert shirt.jpg -fill yellow -fuzz 5% -floodfill +0+0 "#dfdfdf" result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm. So a great answer!!! But just not possible. Maybe you can give 1 complete command line based on my question for future readers with a solid background question and I can accept it. Great!!